# storing feet/inches in DB

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have many different strings with feet/inches like this:

```
10 feet and 8 1/4 inches 
7 feet and 4 3/8 inches
```

I need to store it to DB (I use MS SQL)
How to do it the best way? I see the following approaches:

1. store separately. One field for feet, one field for numerator and one field for denominator. I.e. first string will be:

> feet: 10
>
> numerator: 33 (4*8 + 1)
>
> denominator: 4

2. store in millimeters. In this case I can't restore to simple fractions as client wants to see
3. store in inches, but in decimals. The same problem, can't restore to simple fractions.

How to solve this problem by elegant way in MS SQL? Thank you

Comment: If you need to get back to the original but also need to use the numbers in the database for calculations, I would store 4 columns - feet, inches, numerator, denominator. The latter two will need to be NULL or some magic value to indicate no fraction of inch. You can always generate the string at the beginning of the question from that, and while you *could* build extensive CASE expressions to work back from, say, `.375` to `3/8`, I don't see a ton of benefit there in saving one tinyint colomn.

Comment: I would use 2 integer fields.  Inches and fracInches.  For the frac inches take the denominator and multiply by 100, then add the numerator.  If there is no fractional portion set the field to zero or null as you prefer.  Zero is probably easier to handle.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thank you. What sense in even 4 ? Probably, even 2 is enough. Problem is the whole application is based on feet/inches, each length parameter will have more than one field...

Comment: @gview, probably, 1 (not zero or null)? Then we not need to think about exceptional situations, just divide inches on fracinches

Comment: What is the harm in 4? At least then you have human readable numbers for feet, inches, fraction of inch, and base of fraction. If you want 2 then store 2 but I thought you asked this question because you didn't like the limitations of doing that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'm just trying to find the best solution :)

Comment: I have no idea what your criteria are for "best." I'm car shopping, what is the "best" car for me?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @AaronBertrand, but this is normalized and it uses a field for displaying the fraction while also keeping the numerator and denominator for use in calculations.

Display value can be set to an empty string when there are no fractions.

```
create table Fractions (
ID int identity(1,1),
DisplayValue varchar(10),
Numerator int,
Denominator int
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for storage and calculation, then another option is to create a CLR User Defined DataType which will allow you to encapsulate your logic inside and use it anywhere within Sql Server (apart from as an indexed field).

[CLR User-Defined Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120.aspx)

The page may talk about 2016, but it's also supported in 2005 upwards.